# JSON and jq updating multiple values

Tags: json, bash, updates, jq

Hi I am trying to perform a calculation within a single "jq" command but I cannot workout how to reference the new values.

Original JSON

```
{
  "Status": "Down",
  "StatusID": "75328241",
  "Start": "2017-03-17 15:06:40",
  "End": "2017-03-17 15:08:37",
  "Period": "1 Minutes "
}
```

My goal is to convert the start and end times to epoch and workout the duration in seconds. Then output the same object with the new values.

When I do this

```
echo $J_SON | jq '.Start |= (strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | mktime),.End |= (strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | mktime)'
```

Output is:

```
{
  "Status": "Down",
  "StatusID": "75328241",
  "Start": 1489763200,
  "End": "2017-03-17 15:08:37",
  "Period": "1 Minutes "
}
{
  "Status": "Down",
  "StatusID": "75328241",
  "Start": "2017-03-17 15:06:40",
  "End": 1489763317,
  "Period": "1 Minutes "
}
```

Which makes sense, the manual says that this is default behaviour.

> Assignment works a little differently in jq than in most programming
>   languages. jq doesn’t distinguish between references to and copies of
>   something - two objects or arrays are either equal or not equal,
>   without any further notion of being “the same object” or “not the same
>   object”.
>
> If an object has two fields which are arrays, .foo and .bar, and you
>   append something to .foo, then .bar will not get bigger, even if
>   you’ve previously set .bar = .foo. If you’re used to programming in
>   languages like Python, Java, Ruby, Javascript, etc. then you can think
>   of it as though jq does a full deep copy of every object before it
>   does the assignment (for performance it doesn’t actually do that, but
>   that’s the general idea).

But I would then like to output the values in epoch as well as seconds.

I managed to successfully get the duration like this:

```
echo $J_SON | jq '.Period = ((.End | strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | mktime)-(.Start | strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | mktime))'
```

**Output**

```
{
  "Status": "Down",
  "StatusID": "75328241",
  "Start": "2017-03-17 15:06:40",
  "End": "2017-03-17 15:08:37",
  "Period": 117
}
```

**Problem:**

I can get the individual values of each variables but not sure how to then concatenate them all in a single output object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could chain together the updates like so:

```
.Start |= (strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | mktime)
| .End |= (strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | mktime)
| .Period = (.End - .Start)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. What I don't understand is the "," filter separator. Why would you use it over a pipe if it only works on the child object of the particular value. I guess it makes sense using it when reading values and making changes on the fly, in that case you would not require piping.